# Google maps, set space for overlays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

let´s say this is the very right of my google map : [image]

i have a box with opacity there containing information, i wonder if there was a way
to let overlays like markers not appear behind the box or define an area for them or add an overall overlay margin padding or sth like let google scroll the map until the infowindow is in full sight as google does when its not on the map

maybe someone has an opinion to this?
could there be an easy overridal?

for ***any*** hint

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) at control-position `RIGHT_CENTER` with a width equal to the width of the box and a height of `0`.

With the height of `0` this control will be hidden, but the API will still recognize this control and will try to pan the infoWindow to a position where it's not covered by the control.

Comment: Brilliant! I guess it would be wiser to create a custom control from the start.